# Bash redirect heredoc output to /dev/null

Tags: bash, io-redirection, heredoc

I have a bash script that invokes psql and executes SQL code:

```sh
sudo -i -u postgres psql <<EOF
SQL COMMANDS;
EOF
```

The SQL part generates a lot of output and I'd like to redirect it to /dev/null. How does one redirect a heredoc to /dev/null ?

Comment: You don't want to redirect the **heredoc**. Actually, the heredoc **is** a redirection, in that it redirects the stdin of _postgres_. You want to redirect the **output** of the _postgres_ command. This is done by `>/dev/null`. Note that this would not redirect the standard error.

Comment: Respectfully the linked question is about piping to a file; it's not clear from that answer that you can similarly deal with STDOUT and STDERR. This answer does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trivially

```
postgres psql <<EOF >/dev/null
  SQL COMMANDS;
EOF
```

The `<<` *token* heredoc delimiter is just another redirection operator; so you can do stuff like

```
postgres psql <<EOF 2>/dev/null |
  SQL COMMANDS;
EOF
while IFS= read -r output; do
    case $output in
      *error*) printf '%s%s%s\n' "$red" "$output" "$plain";;
        *) echo "$output";;
    esac
done
```

where the pipeline which starts on the first line continues after the `EOF` token. (This requires you to have defined screen control codes for red and uncolored text separately; `man tput`.)

Comment: I don't know how postgres is producing its output, but your solution assumes, that error messages are written to stdout, not stderr, since you are throwing away stderr, which is not a good idea IMO.

Comment: Actually, I just ad libbed an example where some output from the database itself sometimes contains the text "error" which should be highlighted. Thanks for the comment; it probably can help someone better understand this.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried but it threw an error at EOF. Then I figured out it was caused by a trailing space at EOF.